# WSUS not detecting clients

Tags: windows-server-2012, wsus

My WSUS server is not detecting my clients, i've deactivated the firewalls, and i've checked that the GPO is applied to the clients. When I do a "wuauclt /detectnow" on the clients this is what I get in the WindowsUpdate.log :

[image]

The file seems pretty positive I think but still not having any computer on the WSUS Server.

What should I do?

Comment: Check this 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate] ' is it pointing at the correct server? You may also want to update your question to mention what version of WSUS and OS (Server 2012r2[?]) you are running it on. Also, I'm guessing your desktops are Vista, are those the only ones?

Comment: if possible you might want to reconsider adding the error log as formatted text instead of a picture, so others who search for the same error are able to see this page.

Comment: Your update log shows no error...so it's no real help to include that screenshot.  The final few lines show the WSUS client acting like no updates are needed and it shows the URL to the WSUS server.  Try the WSUS diag tools here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb466192.aspx

Comment: I looks like your WSUS server isn't configured to gather updates for your clients, or that it hasn't synchronized since your clients first registered with it (clients have to register first, then server synchronizes, then you approve updates, then updates show up on clients).